# virtual memory size is much larger than RES, although there are no mapped files

Tags: linux, memory, process, virtual-memory, memory-mapped-files

The program has much large virtual memory than it's in ram, there is no swapping, since there is a lot of free space in ram. I looked at file descriptors, and there are no large files. This is part of process map:

```
107 00007f97f8021000  65404K -----    [ anon ]
108 00007f97fc000000   2052K rw---    [ anon ]
109 00007f97fc201000  63484K -----    [ anon ]
110 00007f9800000000    272K rw---    [ anon ]
111 00007f9800044000  65264K -----    [ anon ]
112 00007f98043fa000      4K -----    [ anon ]
113 00007f98043fb000  10240K rw---    [ anon ]
```

There are a lot of regions with about 64Kb. If they are allocated in my program, why then ram is only 250mb and virtual 3gb? What means `anon`?